# AWS Athena - Changing field to type "MAP"

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have an AWS athena table created by a Glue crawler, with one of the fields is a string representation of a dictionary where the keys and values are strings e.g: `'{"key1": "value_1", "key2":"value2"}'`

I tried to manually change the field type to `MAP<string,string>` but got an exception `HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas` meaning that the partitions were storing the field as String while the in the schema the field changed to map.

So, I tried to run `MSCK Repair table` but it just restored to type of the column to String.

Is there a way to change the field type without losing the current partitions?

Comment: Change the table schema in the crawler, and enable `Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table`.

Comment: Already done - ran the crawler again and the field changed back to "string"

Comment: Are you changing the schema in the crawler itself?

Comment: Is there a way to do so in the crawler itself? tried with "Alter Table" and tried to manually change the column type under glue "Tables"

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the DataCatalog. You can change the table manually in the console and prevent the crawler from changing the schema: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-schema-changes-prevent

Comment: Did you have any luck?